# What is this 'Run layer action' and how to use it?

Tags: qgis, actions

Following on from this question: [Run QGIS layer Action on all selected features](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237771/run-qgis-layer-action-on-all-selected-features), a possible solution was to create an action in Python which iterated through the layer's selected features.

If you *right-click* in the attribute table, there is a `Run layer action` which appears to be greyed out (`Print information` is an action):

[image: Attribute table]

What is this `Run layer action` option and how can it be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the `Run layer action` is meant to be a menu separator as the action is set to be disabled:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/aad182fdc041bd5e83be5b2b399cae496826c008/src/gui/attributetable/qgsdualview.cpp#L461